# How can a question be migrated and who can do this?

Tags: discussion, migration

I am curious about migrated questions. Who can migrate questions? Normal users or only specific users or user who got the privilege with reputation. If normal users or privileged users can do it, how?

Is it possible to made request migration of questions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two sorts of migrations:

- Site to Meta: The question is taken from the main site and plonked in the meta site. Anybody who can close-vote suggest one of these.
- Site to Site (or another meta): The question is sent somewhere else in the Stack Exchange universe. Only moderators can do this.

If you want something migrating fast, you'll do best just to flag it and we can punch it around

Comment: Thats cool answer thank you .

Comment: Bare in mind we typically don't migrate things to other sites unless the question is a really good fit for that site, or if it has answers already and is decent. If you asked a question and you want it moved (with no answers or comments on it) just flag to be closed off-topic and go ask your question on another site.